# Determine if date is weekday/weekend java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm trying to make it compare what day of the week it is and if it is a weekend then perform an action(not implemented yet) but if I put in today's date 25/11/2016 or tomorrows which is a Saturday 26/11/2016, it still only prints "WEEKDAY". Its not working and I'm stuck :/

```
public static void calcDatePrice(String a, boolean b, double c){
    System.out.println("CALC PRICE METHOD: " + a);
    Double price;
    Date d1 = new Date(a);

    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(d1);
    System.out.println(c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

    if ((c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) 
            || (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SUNDAY)) {  //or sunday   
    System.out.println("WEEKEND PRICE");
    }else {
    System.out.println("WEEKDAY");
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot the `c1.get` in your if: `c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY` not `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SUNDAY`

Comment: Some countries have different weekends. Maybe you find my method to [implement a localized weekend](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PlainDate.html#isWeekend-java.util.Locale-) interesting.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 21):

In your if statement you forgot the c1.get on sunday. Should be like this:

```
if (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY || 
    c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
```

Also why do you send in the boolean b and double c? It's never used.

Comment: for a method I havent wrote yet, I figured since it isnt even working yet there isnt any point for the calculations to be done

Comment: Not all countries have Monday-Friday weekdays. For example, Israel is Sunday-Thursday

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY)  || (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)) { 
    System.out.println("WEEKEND PRICE");
} else {
    System.out.println("WEEKDAY");
}
```

Answer (score -5):

you can use calender.DayofWeek method to find which day it is

```js
Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(Enter Yor Date);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if(check day value is 5 or 6)
  {
   // Weekend Coding
  }
Else
{
  // Weekday Coding
}
```